Inflation in background free models of the universe
There are many authors who are attempting to construct a model of physics that doesn't rely on the objective existence of spacetime.  This is part of the work in quantum gravity.  This leads to things like casual structure models of  physics.  I love this branch of physics as it is so speculative. One of the problems I see is the big bang.  It is fairly well accepted that general relativity is going to break down as one goes back into the beginning of the universe and tries to probe out the origins of the big bang.  It even breaks down at the center of a black hole.
My understanding is that during the inflationary period, the stress-energy tensor of the spacetime had lots of curvature and energy.  The particle creation is through parametric amplification, but it is assumed that the energy is coming from the stress-energy tensor of the spacetime.
If we don't have the background spacetime, how does particle creation happen in the beginning?  Where did all the energy come from?  This is in the case of theories of physics where we try to work with no background.

Technically this isn't even a branch of physics, yet. In physics we are explaining complex observations using simple ones. The simple fact is that there are no observations in these regimes. At best we are exploring (over) extrapolations of current theories or models mathematically. At worst we are confabulating. Currently general relativity doesn't fit the observational data about the universe even at the Newtonian level. We still don't know whether this is due to additional (heavy) quantum fields or because GR is simply wrong even in the weak field regime.

@FlatterMann where about in the weak field regime does GR not reduce to Newton?

@Ben Sprott you maybe interested in Topological field theories https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory#:~:text=In%20a%20topological%20field%20theory,Consequently%2C%20they%20are%20topological%20invariants.

@S.G The possibility that modified Newtonian gravity solves the dark matter problem indicates that both Newton gravity and GR are wrong about the long distance and weak field limit. There is in addition the possibility that gravity is non-Newtonian at short distances (below the 0.1mm scale). This would certainly upset both GR and Planck scale physics considerably.
